# Reinstall package and its installed dependencies

Tags: apt, dpkg

I've got a package installed that is broken (the package itself, not its dependencies). Reinstalling it with `sudo dpkg-reconfigure <package>` or `sudo apt-get --reinstall install <package>` did not do the trick. I'd like to try and reinstall the package, including all its currently installed dependencies. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can check all package dependencies with `apt-cache`:

```
apt-cache depends <package>
```

Using the results of that command, we get the following one, which re-installs `<package>` and its dependencies:

```
apt-cache depends <package> | grep '[ |]Depends: [^<]' | cut -d: -f2 | tr -d ' ' | xargs sudo apt-get --reinstall install -y
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you. I modified the grep argument from `'Depends'` to `'[ |]Depends: [^<]'` to exclude _PreDepends_ and alternative package (_Depends: <package>_) entries. The apt-get arguments would need to be `--reinstall install` to do the actual reinstalling I was after.

Comment: For that you have not tested it, it's pretty brave to post it without further explanation. After all you delete a few packages.

Comment: Nice! I suggest removing the `-y`. It's kind of nice to get a chance to confirm what packages are to be reinstalled.

Comment: @user1202136 To see what packages are to be reinstalled, execute the command after replacing the part `xargs ..........` by just `cat`