# bash: /usr/bin/locale-check: No such file or directory error after i downgraded from ubuntu 18.10 to 18.04

Tags: bash, login, downgrade

After downgrading my Ubuntu from 18.10 to 18.04 when ever trying to login I am getting the following error:

[image: view error screenshot]

And opening the terminal following error displays

> bash: /usr/bin/locale-check: No such file or directory

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Problem fixed by copying missed file '/usr/bin/locale-check' from using another  ubuntu 18.04 PC

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue after downgrading 18.10 to 18.04

> -bash: /usr/bin/locale-check: No such file or directory

In downgrading I had to create this file:
`/etc/apt/preferences.d/preferences`
to force it to downgrade, which was preventing some packages from being downloaded
after removing it and updating/upgrading:

> Note: you may have created a different preferences file so your file below might be named differently

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/preferences.d/preferences
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

That fixed it for me! :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `base-files` package starting with version [`10.1ubuntu2.6` (`bionic-updates` pocket)](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/amd64/base-files/filelist) or newer (`cosmic` and later releases) contains some additional files, compared to the [`bionic` release version](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/base-files/filelist) and older:

- `/etc/profile.d/01-locale-fix.sh`
- `/usr/bin/locale-check`

Files in `/etc` are config files though, which will not normally get removed along with the package, unless you `apt purge` it. Especially during a downgrade, which isn't officially supported anyway, removing such files will not be taken care of.

That is why, after downgrading from a newer version to the one 18.04 initially ships with, you get the "File not found" error - the shell initialization script in `/etc` got left behind as residual config, while the required executable got removed properly according to the requested downgrade. This is also explained in the reply to [@roganartu's rejected bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/base-files/+bug/1837300).

The recommended solution is to fix your software repositories configuration and enable getting packages from the `bionic-updates` pocket again, then upgrading `base-files` to that version. `/usr/bin/locale-check` should be back again.

Alternatively, if you insist on staying with the release pocket and not enabling updates, you will either have to manually delete `/etc/profile.d/01-locale-fix.sh`, or you might possibly try [forcefully purging and reinstalling `base-files`](https://askubuntu.com/q/880414/367990).

Answer (score 1):

Yeah it is caused by the package "base-flies", and I re-installed it by down-grade then upgrade. This is what I have done:

```
$ sudo apt-cache madison base-files
```

Then we can get the accurate version of the package:

> base-files | 10.1ubuntu2.7 | https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
>
> base-files | 10.1ubuntu2.7 | http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
>
> base-files | 10.1ubuntu2.2 | https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
>
> base-files | 10.1ubuntu2.2 | http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
>
> base-files | 10.1ubuntu2 | https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
>
> base-files | 10.1ubuntu2 | http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages

Then choose a version to downgrade:

```
$ sudo apt install base-files=10.1ubuntu2.7
```

The last step is to upgrade:

```
$ sudo apt upgrade base-files
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem after downgrading from 19.04 to 18.04, which involved doing a bunch of package purging, manual dependency conflict resolution, and some temporary version pinning that prevented me from getting packages from `bionic-updates`.

The reason that (re)installing the `base-files` package doesn't work seems to be that `/usr/bin/locale-check` isn't actually present in the LTS packages, though it should be:

```
tl@hotbox:~$ apt-cache policy base-files
base-files:
  Installed: 10.1ubuntu2
  Candidate: 10.1ubuntu2
  Version table:
     10.1ubuntu2.5 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
     10.1ubuntu2.2 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
 *** 10.1ubuntu2 1001
       1001 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
tl@hotbox:~$ apt download base-files=10.1ubuntu2
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 base-files amd64 10.1ubuntu2 [58.2 kB]
Fetched 58.2 kB in 0s (1,000 kB/s)
tl@hotbox:~$ apt download base-files=10.1ubuntu2.2
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 base-files amd64 10.1ubuntu2.2 [58.2 kB]
Fetched 58.2 kB in 0s (189 kB/s)
tl@hotbox:~$ apt download base-files=10.1ubuntu2.5
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 base-files amd64 10.1ubuntu2.5 [60.2 kB]
Fetched 60.2 kB in 0s (975 kB/s)
tl@hotbox:~$ dpkg -c base-files_10.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb | rg "/usr/bin"
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2018-04-24 04:34 ./usr/bin/
tl@hotbox:~$ dpkg -c base-files_10.1ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb | rg "/usr/bin"
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2018-08-20 09:44 ./usr/bin/
tl@hotbox:~$ dpkg -c base-files_10.1ubuntu2.5_amd64.deb | rg "/usr/bin"
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2019-07-08 14:43 ./usr/bin/
-rwxr-xr-x root/root     10240 2019-07-08 14:43 ./usr/bin/locale-check
```

You can therefore fix by either forcibly installing `10.1ubuntu2.5`, or manually extracting the `locale-check` binary from the package.

```
$ sudo apt install base-files=10.1ubuntu2.5
...
$ ls /usr/bin/locale-check
/usr/bin/locale-check
```

Later updates will revert this unless you pin the version, however if this is happening you should probably figure out why you aren't getting your version from `bionic-updates`.

I raised a launchpad bug for this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/base-files/+bug/1837300

Answer (score -1):

It should be fixed by reinstalling the package base-files, which can be done via:

```
sudo apt install base-files
```

Unfortunately, that didn't work, so I simply also copied it from another Ubuntu 18.04 system onto this one.