# No such file or directory error at log in after I downgraded from Ubuntu 18.10 to 18.04

Tags: 18.04, downgrade

I downgraded from 18.10 to 18.04 - and I got the same error as in this question

[bash: /usr/bin/locale-check: No such file or directory error after i downgraded from ubuntu 18.10 to 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1096110/bash-usr-bin-locale-check-no-such-file-or-directory-error-after-i-downgraded)

When I login it says:

```
Error found when loading /etc/profile:
etc/profile.d/01-locale-fix.sh: line 2:/usr/bin/locale-check: no such file or directory

As a result the session will not be configured correctly. 
You should fix the problem as soon as feasible.
```

The file is indeed not there. I can't apply the same solution because I do not have another Ubuntu laptop.

How/where can I find the missing file?

Thank you

Comment: I'm closing this question now because the one you linked yourself is exactly the same problem as yours and it received answers in the meantime.