# Found error when loading /etc/profile:

Tags: boot, upgrade, updates, gnome-terminal

After updating my Ubuntu 18.04 by running...

```
sudo apt-get update &
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

...I get the following error message after each restart my Ubuntu:

```
Error found when loading /etc/profile:  
/etc/profile.d/01-locale-fix.sh:/usr/bin/locale-check:no such file or directory  
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale no such file or directory  
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale no such file or directory  
As a result the session will not be configured correctly.  
You should fix the problem as soon as feasible.
```

and after start **terminal is not opening.**

Comment: Related: [bash: /usr/bin/locale-check: No such file or directory error after i downgraded from ubuntu 18.10 to 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1096110/bash-usr-bin-locale-check-no-such-file-or-directory-error-after-i-downgraded) - possibly the corrected answer should be `sudo apt install --reinstall base-files`