# Errors when installing motd-news-config and upgrading base-files on Ubuntu 18.04.5

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dpkg, dependencies

I'm trying to `apt upgrade` my system, but it fails with:

```
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ubuntu-server : Depends: motd-news-config but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

So I try `apt --fix-broken install` which shows:

```
The following additional packages will be installed:
  base-files motd-news-config
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  motd-news-config
The following packages will be upgraded:
  base-files
```

But it fails with:

```
Preparing to unpack .../base-files_10.1ubuntu2.10_amd64.deb ...
Warning: Stopping motd-news.service, but it can still be activated by:
  motd-news.timer
Unpacking base-files (10.1ubuntu2.10) over (10.1ubuntu2.9) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/base-files_10.1ubuntu2.10_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to create '/usr/bin/locale-check.dpkg-new' (while processing './usr/bin/locale-check'): Operation not permitted
Reinstalling /etc/default/motd-news that was backed-up
motd-news.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/base-files_10.1ubuntu2.10_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

So finally I try `apt install motd-news-config` but it fails with:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 motd-news-config : Breaks: base-files (< 10.1ubuntu2.10) but 10.1ubuntu2.9 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I don't understand what's going on here. It seems that the upgrade requires a version of base-files incompatible with motd-news-config, which is also required for the update. I've also tried searching around for `unable to create '/usr/bin/locale-check.dpkg-new'` which could be the actual source of the errors, but I could not find any information on it. Any help, please?

Update:
List of PPAs from `grep ^ /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`:

```
deb http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
deb http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
deb http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
deb http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
deb http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
```

Comment: Do you have some PPA that is involved with the motd program?

Comment: The specific error is `Operation not permitted`, which is different than a version conflict. There are many possible causes: Disk full, forgot to use `sudo`, changed ownership of that file, etc.

Comment: @David No, I haven't added any PPAs myself.

Comment: Sounds ominous who might have?

Comment: @user535733 I have several GB disk space remaining and am using `sudo`. The `/usr/bin` folder is owned by root. I've tried it with both root and non-root sudo users.

Comment: @David I updated my question with all the PPAs.

Comment: I have same issue and also in DigitalOcean, probably something is broken in their repo?

Comment: Duplicate as here : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1096110/bash-usr-bin-locale-check-no-such-file-or-directory-error-after-i-downgraded

Answer (score 0):

The solution that actually worked for me was to do force install:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-all /var/cache/apt/archives/base-files_10.1ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb
```