# dpkg: error processing package linux-firmware (--configure)

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, debian

I get the following error, when i install/uninstall a package on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine. Please help.

```
sudo apt-get install slack
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  amd64-microcode intel-microcode iucode-tool libstd-rust-1.36 linux-headers-4.15.0-76 linux-headers-4.15.0-76-generic linux-headers-generic-hwe-16.04
  linux-modules-4.15.0-76-generic thermald
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  slack
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 255 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 1,550 B of archives.
After this operation, 25.6 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie/main amd64 slack all 1.2.1 [1,550 B]
Fetched 1,550 B in 4s (361 B/s)   
Selecting previously unselected package slack.
(Reading database ... 438564 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../archives/slack_1.2.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking slack (1.2.1) ...
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.14) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up linux-firmware (1.157.22) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-58-generic
cp: cannot create regular file '/var/tmp/mkinitramfs_LmQYTP/init': No such file or directory
/usr/sbin/mkinitramfs:276: no such file or directory: /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_LmQYTP/conf/arch.conf
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/var/tmp/mkinitramfs_LmQYTP//conf’: File exists
cp: failed to access '/var/tmp/mkinitramfs_LmQYTP//conf/conf.d': Not a directory
touch: cannot touch '/var/tmp/mkinitramfs_LmQYTP/etc/fstab': No such file or directory
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/var/tmp/mkinitramfs_LmQYTP/etc/mtab': No such file or directory
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/var/tmp/mkinitramfs_LmQYTP/sbin’: File exists
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/brltty failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-58-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package linux-firmware (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up linux-image-4.15.0-72-generic (4.15.0-72.81~16.04.1) ...
Setting up slack (1.2.1) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.14) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-58-generic
cp: cannot create regular file '/var/tmp/mkinitramfs_OIbFBx//lib/modules/4.15.0-58-generic/kernel/drivers/phy/samsung/phy-exynos-usb2.ko': No such file or directory
cp: cannot create regular file '/var/tmp/mkinitramfs_OIbFBx//lib/modules/4.15.0-58-generic/kernel/drivers/usb/phy/phy-generic.ko': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove '/var/tmp/mkinitramfs_OIbFBx/lib/modules/4.15.0-58-generic/kernel/drivers': Directory not empty
cp: cannot create regular file '/var/tmp/mkinitramfs_OIbFBx/init': No such file or directory
/usr/sbin/mkinitramfs:276: no such file or directory: /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_OIbFBx/conf/arch.conf
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/var/tmp/mkinitramfs_OIbFBx//conf’: File exists
cp: failed to access '/var/tmp/mkinitramfs_OIbFBx//conf/conf.d': Not a directory
touch: cannot touch '/var/tmp/mkinitramfs_OIbFBx/etc/fstab': No such file or directory
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/var/tmp/mkinitramfs_OIbFBx/etc/mtab': No such file or directory
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/var/tmp/mkinitramfs_OIbFBx/sbin’: File exists
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/brltty failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-58-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for linux-image-4.15.0-72-generic (4.15.0-72.81~16.04.1) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-72-generic
cp: cannot create regular file '/var/tmp/mkinitramfs_c2rv1o//lib/modules/4.15.0-72-generic/kernel/drivers/usb/phy/phy-generic.ko': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove '/var/tmp/mkinitramfs_c2rv1o/lib/modules/4.15.0-72-generic/kernel/drivers': Directory not empty
cp: cannot create regular file '/var/tmp/mkinitramfs_c2rv1o/init': No such file or directory
/usr/sbin/mkinitramfs:276: no such file or directory: /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_c2rv1o/conf/arch.conf
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/var/tmp/mkinitramfs_c2rv1o//conf’: File exists
cp: failed to access '/var/tmp/mkinitramfs_c2rv1o//conf/conf.d': Not a directory
touch: cannot touch '/var/tmp/mkinitramfs_c2rv1o/etc/fstab': No such file or directory
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/var/tmp/mkinitramfs_c2rv1o/etc/mtab': No such file or directory
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/var/tmp/mkinitramfs_c2rv1o/sbin’: File exists
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/brltty failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-72-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.15.0-72-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-firmware
 initramfs-tools
 linux-image-4.15.0-72-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be obtaining slack from `https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie/main`. This I don't recommend. `slack` for all currently supported versions of Ubuntu is available in the Universe repository [here.](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=slack) There also appears to be a large number of packages (255) that you haven't yet updated. I would start there and also clean up as your output suggests with `sudo apt autoremove` Based on your output what actually seems to be blowing up the process is the following packages.

[linux-firmware](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/linux-firmware) ,
[initramfs-tools](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/initramfs-tools) and 
[linux-image-4.15.0-72-generic](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/linux-image-4.15.0-72-generic)

What I would do is attempt to [Reinstall package and its installed dependencies](https://askubuntu.com/questions/275719/reinstall-package-and-its-installed-dependencies) for each of these, paying close atttention to the output to determine if the approach is successful. If not successful, you might have to go so far as to [Command to purge and reinstall package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/880414/command-to-purge-and-reinstall-package) for those that failed.

**Note:** You should also take a closer look at the permissions of and in `/var/tmp` and determine if they are sane. This advice relates to the errors reported regarding `4.15.0-58-generic` which also appears to be unsuccessfully installed.