# mono-run prevents reconfiguration of packages on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, 22.04, mono

Recently I had to reinstall Ubuntu. After returning to Ubuntu 22.04 I restored my `/usr/local/` and `var` folders which caused huge mess in terms of packages being written as installed although when one tries to type the command in terminal they don't seem installed.

Normally I follow the advice [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48431372/removing-broken-packages-in-ubuntu) and it fixes the mess but this time I think I made a bigger mess. As Pinta could not be installed due to `mono-runtime` not configured I removed them both from the system. Now `mono-runtime` seems to be installed but not configured: when I type `sudo apt install mono-runtime` I get

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
mono-runtime is already the newest version (6.8.0.105+dfsg-3.2).
mono-runtime set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
```

but then when I type `Y` I get

```
Setting up mono-runtime (6.8.0.105+dfsg-3.2) ...
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /usr/bin/mono doesn't exist
dpkg: error processing package mono-runtime (--configure):
 installed mono-runtime package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libmono-i18n4.0-cil:
 libmono-i18n4.0-cil depends on mono-runtime (>= 6.8.0.105); however:
  Package mono-runtime is not configured yet.
 libmono-i18n4.0-cil depends on mono-runtime (<< 6.8.0.106); however:
  Package mono-runtime is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libmono-i18n4.0-cil (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libmono-i18n-west4.0-cil:
 libmono-i18n-west4.0-cil depends on libmono-i18n4.0-cil (>= 4.0.0~alpha1); however:
  Package libmono-i18n4.0-cil is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libmono-i18n-west4.0-cil (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libmono-corlib4.5-cil:
 libmono-corlib4.5-cil depends on mono-runtime (>= 6.8.0.105); however:
  Package mono-runtime is not configured yet.
 libmono-corlib4.5-cil dependNo apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                                                       No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                            s on mono-runtime (<< 6.8.0.106); however:
  Package mono-runtime is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libmono-corlib4.5-cil (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mono-runtime
 libmono-i18n4.0-cil
 libmono-i18n-west4.0-cil
 libmono-corlib4.5-cil
```

Does anybody has the slightest idea how to solve this problem without formatting the system all over again?

Comment: try the suggestions from [this website](https://linuxhint.com/apt_get_fix_missing_broken_packages/). This is a mess and the easiest way to get out of it is probably to reinstall and *not* mess up installed packages by copy-pasting things where they don't belong. Some of the commands in the linked page may, however, fix some of the inconsistencies with your system

Comment: @Esther thanks. Tried them all. None worked. So that means I need to re-format all again?

Comment: for this specifically, you can try installing with `--reinstall` to see if it installs "from scratch". You can also try `--reinstall`ing all of its dependencies using [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/275733/1083397). However, it is quite possible that `apt` is so broken it is harder to fix than to reinstall, and you will likely come across these kinds of issues again and again even if you get it working this time

Comment: @Esther thanks a lot. I didn't think on apt-cache at all. That resurrected mono-runtime indeed. I guess this "plaster" should suffice for now.